# jquery datepicker, show the preceeding months

Tags: jquery

I would like the datepicker on my page to show both the current month and the preceding three months on click.

I have tried setting `numberOfMonths:-3`  with no success. I have also set  `showOtherMonths: true`. I realize that number of months must be set at 2 or greater. Is there a workaround?

Comment: thinking this through.. I think I need to set the current month as current month-3..then set numberOfMonths:3

Comment: or customize the plugin yourself

Comment: Have you looked at the examples? Seems that http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max would give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
$("input.datepicker").datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: 'MM d, yy',

  defaultDate: "-2MM",
  numberOfMonths: 3,
showOtherMonths: true
});
```

Comment: Is this the code you tried that doesn't work, or is this the answer to your question?

Comment: This is my Answer. I thought I posted it as an answer. The forum won't let me"accept it as my answer" yet.